# average function not returning correct output after editing values

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS, and I have a slight problem.  I have a list of cities that I would like to compute the average temperature, and for some reason, after editing the temperature values in the list of cities, the function to compute the average temperature is returning incorrect values.  It returns the correct value after loading the page, but after editing the temperature values I get incorrect results.

Here is my code:

```
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <title>Weather Comparison</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller='WeatherController'>
<h1>Weather Comparison</h1>
<div ng-repeat='item in items'>
    <span>{{item.city}}</span>
    <input ng-model='item.temp'>
    <input ng-model='item.humidity'>
    <input ng-model='item.wind'>
    <input ng-model='item.cloudiness'>
</div>
<div>The average temperature is {{avgTemp}}</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function WeatherController($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
        {city: 'Phoenix,AZ', temp: 38, humidity: 10, wind: 3, cloudiness: 10},
        {city: 'Atlanta,GA', temp: 30, humidity: 80, wind: 7, cloudiness: 40},
        {city: 'Honolulu,HI', temp: 32, humidity: 75, wind: 8, cloudiness: 30}
    ];

    //returns incorrect average values after editing default temperature values
    $scope.$watch(function() {
        var sum = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
            sum += $scope.items[i].temp;
        }
        $scope.avgTemp = sum / $scope.items.length;
   });
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It would be helpful if you set up a plunkr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The temperature is a string and you need to convert it to an integer ([**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/e8ufd1XNGEDF4gZJrK0p?p=preview)):

```
sum += parseInt($scope.items[i].temp, 10);
```

Or if you want to use floats:

```
sum += parseFloat($scope.items[i].temp);
```

Comment: Thanks.  Instead of parseInt, I used parseFloat, and it worked.

Comment: No problem. Only depends on how accurate you want it to be.

Comment: Keep in mind that there are two args to `parseInt(value, radix)` where the radix defaults to base-8 if not specified. In other words, when parsing an integer in JS that's a base-10 number, use `parseInt(value, 10);`

Comment: @DougSwain Thanks for the reminder, updated the answer. Although I think the default 8 is not absolutely correct. It depends on the input string.

Comment: @MarcelGwerder good point. It does look like it's dependent on the input. Although what it chooses to do appears to be implementation dependent. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt